# couldn't find valid index for shard key mongodb4.2

Tags: indexing, collections, sharding

There is a problem in the sharding cluster of mongodb 4.2. When sharding a collection, it is clear that there is an index and the name is not wrong, but there is no available index "errmsg": "couldn't find valid index for shard key", and there is no array index on the collection.
This is the index:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "height" : "hashed"
    },
    "name" : "height_hashed",
    "ns" : "filscan.msg",
    "background" : true
}
```

This is the creation statement:
`sh.shardCollection("filscan.msg",{"height": "hashed"})`
This is an error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "couldn't find valid index for shard key",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1580971229, 57),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1580971229, 57),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : 
BinData(0,"ZpHl5ZMJWxsEytfna7ZeKGJsPYI="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6779037467879145502")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this same issue. I have opened a ticket on the Mongo JIRA https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-48471 but so far no response.

Comment: Same issue. Voted for the @GavinAiken's ticket.